# Bibtex styles - undefined control sequence

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, chicago-style, harvard-style

The code below shows a .bib file generated with KBibTex which is meant to be a general database for some articles to be written from now on.

```
@comment{x-kbibtex-personnameformatting=<%l><, %f>}

@book{leh,
author = "Cox, Michael M. and Nelson, David L.",
edition = "5",
publisher = "Omega",
title = "{Lehninger: Principles of Biochemistry}",
year = "2007"
}

@book{lev1,
author = "Levine, Ira N.",
edition = "5",
publisher = "McGraw Hill",
title = "{F{\'i}sicoqu{\'i}mica}",
volume = "1",
year = "2004"
}

@book{lev2,
author = "Levine, Ira N.",
edition = "5",
publisher = "McGraw Hill",
title = "{F{\'i}sicoqu{\'i}mica}",
volume = "2",
year = "2004"
}

@book{reg,
author = "Gonz{\'a}lez, J. R. Regueiro and Lamesa, C. L{\'o}pez and Rodr{\'i}guez, S. Gonz{\'a}lez and Naves, E. Mart{\'i}nez",
booktitle = "{Biolog{\'i}a y patolog{\'i}a del sistema inmune}",
edition = "4",
publisher = "Panamericana",
title = "{Inmunolog{\'i}a}",
year = "2010"
}
```

I am well able to use it with some styles such as plain, vancouver, ieeetr, etc. However, when using some others, specially chicago and harvard based, I obtain error messages.

For example: when using dcu (harvard based) I get:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   l.3 \harvarditem
>                   {Cox \harvardand\ Nelson}{2007}{leh}
>   ?

As that sequence is not written on the .bib, it must be, odd enough, generated by bibtex into .bbl.

Any idea how to fix this? Do I need to edit the .bbl? How to?

Thanks in advance to all of you.

P.S.: might be useful to notice I am using the article template provided by texworks with babel for spanish.

**EDIT Oct 9 2013**

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{Docs/latex/books.bib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\end{document}
```

where books.bib is the code I post before.

However, when making the MWE I found that compiling has some sort of influence in the error. I. e.: I was able to run it properly only once right after erasing the useless parts of the document but never after, even though, I 've tried deleting all the auxiliar files. I am even more puzzled than before.

Hope this helps.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You're missing `\usepackage{harvard}`. Don't add the `.bib` extension in the argument to `\bibliography`.

Comment: @egreg well, the solution was as simple as that. However, .bib extension did no harm to the path.
Post an answer and I'll mark it right as soon as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `dcu` bibliography style cannot be used “alone”, but it must be supplemented by the call to the `harvard` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{harvard}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{Docs/latex/books.bib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\end{document}
```

You may be willing to look at the `natbib` package that also features “Harvard style” citations.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to considering the `harvard` citation management package, as already suggested by @egreg in his answer, you may want to look into using the `har2nat` and `natbib` packages. As the package's name suggests, the `har2nat` package "translates" the commands provided by the `harvard` package (and used by the bibliography styles that come with the `harvard` package, such as `dcu`) into commands understood by the `natbib` package.

Will you see a big difference in performance between the `harvard` and `natbib`/`har2nat` options. Not really, ***unless*** you also use the `hyperref` package. The hyperref manual has the following to say about its compatibility with citation management packages:

> Package `hyperref` aims to cooperate with other packages, but there are several possible sources for conflict, such as [p]ackages that manipulate the bibliographic mechanism. Peter Williams' `harvard` package is supported. However, the recommended package is Patrick Daly's `natbib` package that has specific `hyperref` hooks to allow reliable interaction. This package covers a very wide variety of layouts and citation styles, all of which work with `hyperref`.

In short, even though the `harvard` package is "supported", interoperability and compatibility are most pronounced with the `natbib` package. It was precisely a need to be able to use `hyperref` that led me, several years ago by now, to switch from the `harvard` package to the `natbib` package (and the `har2nat` package if I was using a harvard-based style file such as `dcu`).

Comment: @jasikevicius23 - that should work. (I can't be entirely sure, of course, since I don't have your `.bib` file...) Do make sure to use the citation commands provided by the `natbib` package, such as `\citet`, `\citep`, and `\citeauthor`. When the `natbib` package is used, the basic-LaTeX `\cite` command works like `\citet`.

Comment: worked perfectly for me using \cite. @mico You do have the .bib above, at the question, if you're willing to test it yourself.

Comment: @jasikevicius23 - I tried out @egreg's MWE on the bib items in your posting (with `\nocite{*}` replaced with the four individual `\cite` commands), loading either the `harvard` package or the combination of `har2nat` and `natbib` packages. Everything compiled under pdfLaTeX. If `harvard` is loaded, none of the four citations end up being turned into hyperlinks to the respective bib entries. With `har2nat` and `natbib` loaded, the hyperlinking worked flawlessly.